# Why infinite-scroll in react don't see data from function map()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror, infinite-scroll

I have a problem with this code:

```
<InfiniteScroll
  dataLength={beers.length}
  next={fetchMoreBeers}
  hasMore={true}
  loader={<p>Loading ...</p>}
  endMessage={<p id="beers-end">No more beers :(</p>}
>
  {beers.map((beer, index) => (
    <div key={index}>
      <Link
        to={{
          pathname: `/beer/${beer.id}`,
          state: { beer: beer.id },
        }}
      >
        <div className="beer-wrapper">
          <div className="beer">
            <img
              className="beer-img"
              src={beer.image_url}
              alt={beer.name}
            />
            <p className="beer-name">
              {beer.name.length < 15
                ? `${beer.name}`
                : `${beer.name.substring(0, 20)}...`}
            </p>
            <p className="beer-tagline">
              {beer.tagline.length < 20
                ? `${beer.tagline}`
                : `${beer.tagline.substring(0, 25)}...`}
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Link>
      <Route path="/beer/:id" component={Beer} />
    </div>
  ))}
</InfiniteScroll>;
```

And when the page is scrolled the error occurs:

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"

for this line:

```
pathname: `/beer/${beer.id}`,
```

This seems like InfiniteScroll doesn't see the data from map() function ....

Maybe some of you know how to fix this problem?

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Can you try {beers && beers.map((beer, index) => ( this should work. Also if possible share your beers data as well so that it's easy to identify and suggest quick solution

Comment: Hi! I was trying your code, but it is not working :( The data are from this api: https://punkapi.com/documentation/v2

Comment: ok. Can you also share the code wr you are fetching beers data

Comment: This is it: ` componentDidMount = async () => {
    await fetch('https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers', {
      method: 'get'
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          beers: json
        })
      }
    );
  }`

Comment: @IwonaHajczewska in your render it says `beers` shouldnt it be `this.state.beers`? Do you assign `this.state.beers` to `beers` variable at the beginning of render and use it or is it the mistake?:)

Comment: Yes, I add this code const { beers, fetchMoreBeers } = this.props

Comment: and `congole.logs`? do they return proper data? What is logged for `beer` just before error?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the issue is with template literals. When we add template literals directly it throws such issues. I experienced the same in my projects.

May be you can try in below way

```
render(){
  const { beers } = this.props;
  const beerItems = beers.map((beer, index) => {
      let pathName = `/beer/${beer.id}`;
              return (
                <div key={index}>
                    <Link to={{ 
                        pathname: {pathName},
                        state: {"beer": beer.id}
                    }} >
                        <div className="beer-wrapper">       
                            <div className="beer">
                                <img className="beer-img" src={beer.image_url} alt={beer.name} />
                                <p className="beer-name">
                                    {beer.name.length < 15 ? beer.name : beer.name.substring(0, 20) }
                                </p>
                                <p className="beer-tagline">
                                    {beer.tagline.length < 20 ? beer.tagline : beer.tagline.substring(0, 25) }
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </Link>
                    <Route path="/beer/:id" component={Beer} />
                </div>    
            )
            }

  return(
    <InfiniteScroll
            dataLength={beers.length}
            next={fetchMoreBeers}
            hasMore={true}
            loader={<p>Loading ...</p>}
            endMessage={<p id="beers-end">No more beers :(</p>}
        >    
            {beerItems}
        </InfiniteScroll>
  )
}
```

Comment: it is not that. Her syntax is OK, it's ES6 and returning block of code, so it is on point.

Comment: beers.map((beer, index) => ( how come this is valid?

Comment: arrow function without { returns its internals by default. Regular bracket ( is used just to wrap block of code here. 
Check this fiddle, it uses same syntax in ex. line 60:
https://jsfiddle.net/n5u2wwjg/173219/

Comment: Haaa I am hearing that for the first time. Thanks for helping me with the doc.

Comment: Perhaps the issue is with template literals

Comment: Template literals also seems on point. 

@IwonaHajczewska
can you log `beers` array at the beginning of render and see if there s actually anything in an array?
Also can you log `beer` at the beginning of your `map` loop? We ll see what it is if not `beer`

Comment: @Think-Twice your code wont work. `const beers = beers.map`. It should be `const beer = this.state.beers.map`

Comment: Looks like she is getting beers from props. I changed const beers to const beerItems

Comment: @Thinm-Twice - thanks for your tip, that this is not working - I think that this problem is not on this one line with beer.id but with all beer.some_param

Comment: @IwonaHajczewska yes wherever you use template literals will be a problem

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is an `undefined` value stored in `beers` array. Try to filter them out, like so:

```
beers.filter(Boolean).map((beer, index) => ( 
  // ... 
)
```

Also, I've noticed that `hasMore` prop is always set to `true`. To see if it helps, try something like:

```
<InfiniteScroll
  dataLength={beers.length}
  next={fetchMoreBeers}
  hasMore={beers.length < 25} // or hasMore={this.state.hasMore}
  loader={<p>Loading ...</p>}
  endMessage={<p id="beers-end">No more beers :(</p>}
> ...
```

**EDIT:**

You are using `Array.from({ length: 20 }))`. The output array will contain 20 `undefined` values. That is why you should consider `beers.filter(Boolean)`.

I suppose this is what you really meant:

```
this.setState({ 
  items: this.state.beers.concat(Array.from(this.state.beers))
})
```

or:

```
this.setState({ 
  items: [...this.state.beers, ...this.state.beers]
})
```

Comment: If this would be a true, that in `beers` is stored value `undefined` then any records will be display on page .... On page are displayed 20 items from 'beers' and only if page is scrolled this error is occured ...

Comment: yes in default this Api set you 25 records and the max items from data is 80 ... If this is a problem for this component?

Comment: It's hard to tell.. Have you tried `hasMore={beers.length < 25}`?

Comment: `fetchMoreBeers = () => {
    if (this.state.beers.length >= 25) {
      this.setState({ hasMore: false });
      return;
    }
    // a fake async api call like which sends
    // 20 more records in .5 secs
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        items: this.state.beers.concat(Array.from({ length: 20 }))
      });
    }, 500);
  };`

Answer (score 0):

You should check for the status code when fetching the beers. `fetch` will still let you do your thing even if the request failed. If you exceed your endpoint data limit, you'll get this data added to your beer array:

```js
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "Invalid query params",
  "data": [{
    "param": "per_page",
    "msg": "Must be a number greater than 0 and less than 80",
    "value": "100"
  }]
}
```

As you can see there's no `id` param there which makes this strange error to show up.

Including a json schema validator (like https://ajv.js.org/) to make sure the data is in expected format would be a perfect choice.

Comment: Hi! In documentation of this component is that code: Array.from({ length: 20 })). You can see this on that page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroll-component in this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/439v8rmqm0

Answer (score 0):

I think that this problem is because of data records limitations in this Api .